# React Native: Is using .map instead of Flatlist ok?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it ok to use .map to render component lists instead of Flatlist ( performance wise) for lists that are 50 items at max?

For me a simple map + ScrollView feels easier and more intuitive than FlalistNative: Is using .map instead of Flatlist ok?

Answer (score 1):

Flatlist uses lazyloading which means it only loads what is needed on the screen. So its performance would be better that simple map. But as you have mentioned your are using small list any of them will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to speed rendering components, using Flatlist win this feature. As I observe approximately around 30% Flatlist is faster in rendering than using Map. Because Flatlist can able to cache the previous data when it comes to displaying in DOM.

FlatList has lazy loading (it only shows what's on screen, so it can be more performant if you have a huge list)

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use map to render a component, however, to improve the performance I'd suggest using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) to cache the iterated elements.